# RegEx for a date format

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have a string like this:

```
07-MAY-07 Hello World 07-MAY-07 Hello Again
```

So the pattern is, DD-MMM-YY, where MMM is the three letter format for a month. What Regular Expression will break up this string into:

```
07-MAY-07 Hello World
07-MAY-07 Hello Again
```

===================

Using Jason's code below modified for C#,

```
string input = @"07-MAY-07 Hello World 07-MAY-07 Hello Again";   
string pattern = @"(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}\s)(\D*|\s)";

string[] results = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
results.Dump();

Console.WriteLine("Length = {0}", results.Count());
foreach (string split in results) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", split);
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I get embedded blank lines?

```
Length = 7
''

'07-MAY-07 '

'Hello World '

''

'07-MAY-07 '

'Hello Again'

''
```

I don't even understand why I am getting the blank lines...?

===========================

Ok, I changed the regex to @"(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})";

Now I get one blank line at the beginning. Very minor, but still I don't understand why?

Length = 5
''

'07-MAY-07'

' Hello World '

'07-MAY-07'

' Hello Again'

''

Also, since the MMM cannot be any three letters, is there a way to change the regex so that those three letters are forced to be (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)?

Comment: I added a `\n` new line to my code as per the original request.  I don't know C#, but if you added that in.. you might try to remove it.

Comment: Since the other solutions did not answer your empty line question or take into account your `JAN|FEB|MAR|...`, suggestion, I added an answer of my own which addresses these.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex (not bullet-proof) would be:

```
(\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d .*?(?=(\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d|$)))
```

This captures the lines, using a look-ahead of another match or end of line.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "07-MAY-07 Hello World 07-MAY-07 Hello Again";

str = str.replace(/(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}\s)(\D*|\s)/, '$1$2\n');

alert(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DAYUG/

Comment: Thank you both. This almost works. There appears to be blank lines in there too!?     Output is Length = 7
''

'07-MAY-07 '

'Hello World '

''

'07-MAY-07 '

'Hello Again'

''

Comment: Sort of.  Not blank lines but new lines. See, I broke this into groups.  So the first item returned from the regex (`$1`) is the date and the second item (`$2`) is the text, followed by a (`\n`) new line.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  [0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2}\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*
```

you can test the regex before using it [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? in perl you can do something like

```
$s = "07-MAY-07 Hello World 07-MAY-07 Hello Again";
$s =~ s/\s(\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d)/\n$1/g;
print $s;
```

result

```
07-MAY-07 Hello World
07-MAY-07 Hello Again
```

Answer (score 0):

The blank line is caused by your `regex.Split` method.  The first match is at the begining, so you get an extra entry in your array.  You can do this instead:

```
string input = "07-MAY-07 Hello World 07-MAY-07 Hello Again";
Regex regex =
   new Regex(
      @"(\d{2}-(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\d{2})(.(?!\d{2}-(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\d{2}))*",
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches (input))
{
   Console.WriteLine (match.Value);
}
```

The expression looks for your date (including exact 3-char months), then matches all the text until the next date string.  The next match should begin right after the previous match.

Comment: Can u tell what (in the regex) matches the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Milde, `\A` matches the begining of the string. `^` matches the begining of a line.

Comment: you wrote, that the first match (the blank line) is at the beginning, but there is no \A in the regex. Is this because of the Split method you mentioned above?

Comment: @Milde, Sorry.  I was referring specifically to the OP's example `@"07-MAY-07 Hello World 07-MAY-07 Hello Again"`.  The `.Split` method created an empty string as the first string because the first match was at position 0 in the string.